Letter under double and triple integrals
There are several letters that can be under a double integral, like $S$, $R$, or $C$ for line integrals. What do all of these letters stand for?
$$
\iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{n} \, \mathrm{d}S
=
\iint_R \langle -2,-2,-2\rangle \cdot \left\langle \frac x z, \frac y z, 1 \right \rangle \, \mathrm{d}A
$$

They mean what the specific text says they mean.

They stand for the region of integration. So $S$ and $R$ in your example are presumably subsets of the plane, and the $C$ you talk about in curve integrals would be the curve.
We can use them with regular integrals as well. If $I$ is the interval $[0,5]$ then $\displaystyle \int_0^5$ and $\displaystyle \int_I$ mean exactly the same thing. But for all other types of integral, two numbers isn't enough to decide the region of integration, so we have to stick to the $\displaystyle \int_I$ way of writing.

It depends on the context, but generally it tells you the set you are integrating over. Typically,
$$
\int_C f(\vec r) \, \mathrm{d}s
\qquad
\oint_C f(\vec r) \, \mathrm{d}s
$$
will tell you you are integrating over a curve $C$ (a closed one in the latter case). In the event you have something like
$$
\iint_R f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}A
$$
this usually means you are integrating over a 2-dimensional surface $R$ in the $x,y$ plane. Whereas
$$
\iint_S f(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}\vec S
$$
usually means we're integrating over an oriented surface $S$ in 3-dimensional space. And
$$
\iiint_V f(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}V
$$
usually means we're integrating over some 3-dimensional volume $V$.
Ultimately, though, what the letters mean depend on context. Typically, as stated,

$C$ is curves or lines (here's Paul's Online Math Notes on line integrals)
$R$ for regions/areas (here's Paul's Online Math Notes on double integrals)
$S$ for surfaces (here's Paul's Online Math Notes on surface integrals)
$V$ for volumes (here's Paul's Online Math Notes on triple integrals)

...but this does not always have to be the case (i.e. it is by no means required it be any of these), so you'll have to figure out the details from context.
As an analogy, perhaps, we could rewrite
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{[a,b]} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
if this helps at all.
